How to prevent multiple react native bundles loads because of changing react native android language using AppCompatDelegat.setApplicationLocales
I am trying to create a react native android module that handles changing the app langauge on the native level.
I created a TurboModule and I have a function that changes the language as such:
override fun setLocale(locale: String) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(locale))
}

AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales restarts the app, suboptimal but ok.
My issue is that after the app is restarted a new bundle seems to load because in the console I see mutiple:
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

and
 (NOBRIDGE) LOG  Running "SampleApp" with {"rootTag":11,"initialProps":{},"fabric":true}

Here is how the console looks on a fresh app start:

and here is how the console looks like after changing the language:

They increase as many times as you change the language. How do I prevent the multiple bundle load?

Not a fix but a workaround is preventing the reboot on Android in the AndroidManifest.xml by setting configChanges on the <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale" and then restart RN on your own terms. Note that both values in configChanges are necessary in order for this to work.
